# How to get the path to a properties file and pass it to a bean at runtime

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that is created by Spring.  The actual class resides in a different JAR than Spring.  This bean is passed a path as a constructor argument.  However, I am having difficulty retrieving a handle to the file.  The file is in WEB-INF/classes/.  I've tried relative pathing based on WEB-INF, but obviously that didn't work.

XML:

```
 <bean id="configurationManager" class="package.ConfigurationManager" 
      scope="singleton">           
      <property name="configurationMapping">
            <bean class="package.PropertiesFileConfigurationMapper">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
                    <value>/path/to/file</value>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean> 
      </property>                     
</bean>
```

Bean:

```
public class ConfigurationMapper {

    public ConfigurationMapper(String resource) {
            _map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String property = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(resourcePath);
            reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            while ((property = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (property.matches("(.+)=(.+)")) {
                    String[] temp = property.split("(.+)=(.+)");
                    _map.put(temp[0], temp[1]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }

    //other methods to manipulate settings
}
```

How can I get the proper path to the `rm.properties` file and pass it to the bean at runtime?

Edit: Added constructor code.

Edit: I got it.  I changed the constructor argument to no longer take a path.  It now takes a Resource, so Spring has found the resource that I wanted loaded.

Comment: try the classpath suffix. I mean classpath:filpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.io.File` and `FileReader` only work for actual files. A resource packed inside a JAR file isn't itself a file.

The easiest way to load it is as a classpath resource:

Replace this:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(resourcePath);
reader = new BufferedReader(file);
```

with something like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Better yet, use Spring's `Resource` abstraction, by declaring the constructor parameter as `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`:

```
public ConfigurationMapper(Resource resource) {
   ...
   InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

When you then supply the path:

```
<constructor-arg value="classpath:/path/to/file"/>
```

Spring will automatically create a `ClasspathResource` for that path (using a classpath) , and pass it to your constructor.

Comment: Yes.  This is what I did, but moments before you suggested it I found an article mentioning this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a complex resource declarations.  You can declare files, classpath, or extend it with your own ideas.  Everything is based on resource URIs.  Since your file is in a jar file so you can load it using classpath:

```
        <bean class="package.PropertiesFileConfigurationMapper">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>classpath:/path/to/file/in/jar</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
```

Now modify your constructor to take a java.io.InputStream.

```
public ConfigurationMapper(InputStream resource) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( resource ) );
    ....
}
```