# Spring - properties filte to Map<String, Class<Object>>

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, properties, code-injection

I'm trying to load a class passing a properties file as parameter on the constructor but I'm getting a cast exception: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`. 
Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

myMap.properties

```
BAR=com.mycomp.myapp.Bar
```

application-context.xml looks like this:

```
<util:properties id="myMap" 
    location="classpath:myMap.properties" 
    local-override="false" 
    value-type="java.lang.Class" />   


<bean id="foo" class="com.mycomp.myapp.Foo">
    <constructor-arg name="myMap" ref="myMap"/>
</bean>
```

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
    private Map<String, Class<Object>> myMap;

    public Foo(Map<String, Class<Object>> myMap){
        this.myMap = myMap;
        Class<Object> barClass = myMap.get("BAR"); //failure point
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like :

Context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myMap.properties"/>
<bean id="foo" class="com.mycomp.myapp.Foo">
  <constructor-arg value="${BAR}" />
</bean>
```

Foo:

```
public class Foo {
private String bar;

  public Foo(String bar){
      this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Or if you really need whole file you can just pass path to your property file and load it in constructor.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but that won't work for me. My Foo class is a factory I'll need to pass the map object to know which object I'll create.

Comment: Thanks, then seems like something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246369/how-to-get-the-path-to-a-properties-file-and-pass-it-to-a-bean-at-runtime