# Loading a properties file from a file path in Spring

Tags: java, spring, filepath

I have the following bean in my application context:

```
<bean id="httpClient" factory-method="createHttpClient" class="com.http.httpclient.HttpClientFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="httpConfig" class="com.http.httpclient.HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl">
            <constructor-arg value="httpclient.properties"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Where `httpclient.properties` is the name of my properties file. I use this parameter in my `HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl` to read the file (Don't mind the error handling too much):

```
public HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl(String fileName) {
  try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("resource/src/main/properties/" + fileName)) {
     properties.load(inputStream);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     LOG.error("Could not find properties file");
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to pass the whole file location within the bean so I don't have to do add the path `resource/src/main/properties` while creating the `InputStream`?

I've tried with `classpath:httpclient.properties` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `resource/src/main/properties/` in your classpath? In any case, why don't you pass `resource/src/main/properties/httpclient.properties` as `constructor-arg`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to pass the whole location in case it changes. I just wanted to give the file name. And yes, the folder is in my classpath.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7246629/1898397 this answer looks relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong, the file is in the classpath (`src/main/resources` is added to the classpath and files in there are copied to the root of the classpath. In your case in a sub directory named `properties`). Instead of a `String` I suggest you use `Resource` or `Properties` instead.

```
public HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl(Resource res) {
  try(InputStream inputStream = res.getInputStream()) { 
      properties.load(inputStream);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   LOG.error("Could not find properties file");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Then in your configuration you can simply write the following:

```
<bean id="httpClient" factory-method="createHttpClient" class="com.http.httpclient.HttpClientFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="httpConfig" class="com.http.httpclient.HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl">
            <constructor-arg value="classpath:properties/httpclient.properties"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Or even better don't even bother with loading the properties but simply pass them to the constructor and let Spring do all the hard loading for you.

```
public HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl(final Properties properties) {
    this.properties=properties
}
```

Then use the `util:properties` to load the properties and simply reference it for the constructor.

```
<util:properties id="httpProps" location="classpath:properties/httpclient.properties" />

<bean id="httpClient" factory-method="createHttpClient" class="com.http.httpclient.HttpClientFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="httpConfig" class="com.http.httpclient.HttpClientParamsConfigurationImpl">
            <constructor-arg ref="httpProps"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The last option keeps your code clean and saves you from doing loading etc.